# How do I add an ID to the ul tag of a menu?

Tags: routes, theming

I am able to add unique ids to menu links by either adding code to my theme's template file or by using a menu module; however, I would like to add a unique id to the ul tag that encapsulates the menu li links.  The reason that I would like to implement this is to style the menu as a whole instead of the menu's individual links.   My ultimate goal is to take the whole menu and float it to the right in the header-top region of drupal.  I am rather new to Drupal so, perhaps there is another way to achieve this?

I originally attempted custom css styles using the skinr module without success.  The skinr module was able to move the menu's title to the right, but the menu's links were still located at the left of header-top.

My setup consists of Drupal 7

*UPDATE*
I was able to add a custom CSS class "user-menu" to the user-menu block.  Next I added a custom css to mix-and-match-style.css

css code:

```
.user-menu ul li {
     padding: 0;
     float: right;
}
```

The css code seems to float: right the menu, but the links are not ordered properly once floated to the right.  The correct order of the links should be "My account | Log out".  When the list is floated to the right the order changed to: "Log out My account |"

Is that a bug or am I not understanding something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `theme_menu_tree`

```
function theme_menu_tree($variables) {
  return '<ul class="menu">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
}
```

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/theme_menu_tree/7

You can print this menu tree

```
template_preprocess_menu_tree
```

[hereis api](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/template_preprocess_menu_tree/7)

Pre process the menu tree OR Call the menu theme to print it as you want. 
Thats all.

Comment: Am I supposed to change 'tree' to the menu name?

Comment: After testing out my question I arrived to the conclusion that I am NOT supposed to change the 'tree to the menu name as doing that throws errors.  I am not exactly sure where to go from here to generate unique class or ID names.  For example, have that function generate "menu-someuniquenumber" as the ul class or id name.

Comment: template_preprocess_menu_tree will help you for sure.

Comment: Ok, I am relatively new to drupal. I am searching google for a learning tutorial about drupal's api calls for this example, but I am not receiving valuable information. I read over drupal's api and the basic example is there; however, I am still unsure how to get this to work.  So far I successfully used theme_menu_tree api.

Comment: template_preprocess_menu_tree can be used to alter the menu tree from your template.php file.

Comment: @NikhilM Where could I place your first code?